# Select statement ignoring parameters?

Tags: c#, select, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

When I use this code it returns every row in the table and i have no idea why.

```
string SelectOleDb = "SELECT Top 1 * From `Employee Info` Where [Employee Name]=@EmployeeName" Order By ID DESC";

OleDbConnection OleDbCon = new OleDbConnection(EmployeeInfo.Properties.Settings.Default.cstrEmployeeInfoDatabase);
OleDbDataAdapter OleDbAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand OleDbCom = new OleDbCommand(SelectOleDb, OleDbCon);
OleDbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", employee_NameComboBox.Text);
OleDbAdpt.SelectCommand = OleDbCom;

DataSet FooDS = new DataSet();
OleDbCon.Open();
OleDbAdpt.Fill(FooDS);
OleDbCon.Close();
OleDbCon.Dispose();
DataTable EmployeeInfo = FooDS.Tables[0];
```

And i even copy pasted a value from the Employee Name column into the text box to verify i was using a valid employee name. I would expect nothing to be returned instead of everything if the statement was incorrect though.

UPDATE: I have also tried removing the Named Paramter "@EmployeeName" and entering a hard corded name surrounded by single quotes. Yet still statement returns every thing in Employee Info

Comment: Your identifier quoting seems a bit schizo...`Employee Info` is using backticks, and `Employee Name` is using brackets.  In my experience, either one or the other will work with a given DBMS, but i don't know of any that support both at once.  What type of DBMS are you using?

Comment: Have you run it in debugger to verify that the values are there?

Comment: I don't believe that OleDb supports named parameters.  Try using question marks in your select string instead of the named parameters.  Be sure to add the parameters in the same order as they appear in the sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have stated that OleDb required a ? and that it did not accept Named Parameters. This is false. I have fixed my code and it is working. The problem at hand was that the Statement required different ways to define spaces.

With the OleDB connection the Table Name if it had a space had to be in EITHER `(Ticks) or  both will work the same.

The confusions begins when you have Column Names with spaces. When the statement is built All column names have to have an _ (Under Score) in place of the Spaces the column names. While both `(Ticks) and  are optional for Column names. All that is REQUIRED is the replacement of " "(Space) with _(under score)

What adds to the confusion is the fact that the table name is REQUIRED to have either `(Ticks) or  and if you do replace a " "(Space) with _(under score) it will not find the table.

My fixed Code:

```
        string SelectOleDb = "SELECT Top 1 * From [Employee Info] Where Employee_Name= @EmployeeName Order By ID DESC";

        OleDbConnection OleDbCon = new OleDbConnection(EmployeeInfo.Properties.Settings.Default.cstrEmployeeInfoDatabase);
        OleDbDataAdapter OleDbAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommand OleDbCom = new OleDbCommand(SelectOleDb, OleDbCon);
        OleDbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", employee_NameComboBox.Text);
        OleDbAdpt.SelectCommand = OleDbCom;

            DataSet EmployeeInfoDS = new DataSet();
            OleDbCon.Open();
            OleDbAdpt.Fill(EmployeeInfoDS);
            OleDbCon.Close();
            OleDbCon.Dispose();
            DataTable EmployeeInfoDT = EmployeeInfoDS.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using two different `DataSet`s:

```
DataSet FooDS = new DataSet();   // <-- FooDS?
OleDbCon.Open();
OleDbAdpt.Fill(ExpediteDS);   // <-- filing a different dataset?
OleDbCon.Close();
OleDbCon.Dispose();
DataTable EmployeeInfo = FooDS.Tables[0];  // <-- not the dataset you just filled!
```

If this is a copy/paste error please post your code *exactly* as you have it - if you try and "dummy" up your code you're going to cause folks to chase rabbits and not expose the real problem.

Comment: That's probably just a typo from where the OP was trying to anonymize the code.  We'll find out soon, though, i guess.  :)

Comment: @DStanley, so the issue is often times corporate policies. I face the same policies. When I post code here you can't have any knowledge of who I work for or what the code is referring to. However, I just have to slowly modify the code I paste so that it's not incriminating in any way. ***I do fully understand your perspective and respect it - it's really a waste of time to chase a problem that's not the real problem because the code posted isn't accurate.***

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I completely understand - just venting a bit :)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thank you, It was a small overlook and i do understand how it can be aggrevating to someone trying to help, i have appologized. But if had read the full question he would have noticed that the issue isn't that EmployeeInfo isn't getting filled, its that the select is returning every value and not Top 1 where Employee Name = MyValue.

Comment: @user2140261 not to belabor the point - but I _did_ read the full question which is how I saw the two different dataset references being used.  I ALSO saw that your `SELECT` has a `TOP 1` clause which made me think that the `SELECT` you posted wasn't the select being executed, which would make sense if you were using two different datasets.  Since there was no indication of how `ExpediteDS` was getting filled  assumed that was happening somewhere else.  All that to say, I pointed out the apparent error that made sense given what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

I tried out a variant of your query and an OLEDB connection to SQL Server using the ? and it worked as expected.  Using a named parameter fails.

As requested, here is the sample:

```
        string SelectOleDb = "SELECT Top 1 * From users Where [application_user_name]=? Order By application_user_id DESC";

        OleDbConnection OleDbCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SERVER\\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=samples;Trusted_Connection=yes");

        OleDbDataAdapter OleDbAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommand OleDbCom = new OleDbCommand(SelectOleDb, OleDbCon);
        OleDbCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", "smith");
        OleDbAdpt.SelectCommand = OleDbCom;

        DataSet ExpediteDS = new DataSet();

        DataSet FooDS = new DataSet();
        OleDbCon.Open();
        OleDbAdpt.Fill(ExpediteDS);
        OleDbCon.Close();
        OleDbCon.Dispose();
```

it is important to note, that with OLEDB, parameter order matters.  You must add them to the ParameterCollection in the order you want them referenced in the query.

Comment: Could you share your variant? I tried to replace the named with a ? and it now says "No value given for one or more required parameters."