# Command text was not set for the command object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ms-access-2007, runtime-error

I am working on a project and getting an error as "Command text was not set for the command object". 
My code is :

```
query = "select Top 10    
                 Name,
                 R_Line2,
                 BirthDate,
                 BirthTime,
                 Height,
                 Weight,
                 BirthCity,
                 BirthCountry,
                 FatherName,
                 MonthlyIncome,
                 FamilyIncome,
                 Add1,
                 Add2,
                 PinCode,
                 Tel1,
                 Tel2
          from InpRegistration  
          where DateDiff('yyyy', [Birthdate],
                  Now()) BETWEEN @AgeFrom AND
                  @AgeTo and Weight BETWEEN @MinWeight AND 
                  @MaxWeight and Height BETWEEN @MinHeight AND @MaxHeight and   
                  MonthlyIncome BETWEEN @MinIncome AND @MaxIncome";

connf.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data   Source=D:\project\Milan_Data.mdb";

connf.Open();

   OleDbCommand cmdf = new OleDbCommand(query, connf);

    cmdf.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeFrom", ddlminage.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeTo", ddlmaxage.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinWeight", ddlweightmin.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxWeight", ddlweightmax.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinHeight", ddlheightmin.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxHeight", ddlheightmax.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinIncome", ddlminincome.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinIncome", ddlmaxincome.SelectedItem.Text);

        OleDbDataAdapter daf = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdf);
        DataSet dsf = new DataSet();
        daf.Fill(dsf);
        Repeater2.DataSource = dsf;
        Repeater2.DataBind();


        connf.Close();
```

Please help me. I am searching on net for this but not getting any solution.[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925508/thrown-exception-c-sharp-command-text-was-not-set-for-the-command-object),. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try declaring a query  variable as a sqlcommand data type

Comment: What you have declared your query as??

Comment: I have declared query as string

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian query is a "string".

Comment: I am not good at c# but I checked some examples and are you sure that you attaching params correctly? Look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/15368537/1692632

Comment: @Darka Thanks for your response. Now I have deleted all the parameters from the query. Now the query is simple "SELECT" query without any conditions, but still I am getting the same error...  Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Command text was not set for the command object.

Comment: example I found is a bit different what you have. It also has  OleDbCon.Open(); after OleDbDataAdapter

Comment: @Darka Ya, I have also seen that example and tried that too... But the error remains same... I don't think it occurred because of conn.open().

Comment: Does it work if you miss out setting the CommandType property.

Comment: @BobVale No, it doesn't working :(

Comment: seems easy steps: http://www.ehow.com/how_5257151_use-oledbdataadapter-c.html So maybe error is not in given example. I don't know :(

Comment: @SantoshKumar change that query  variable datatype string to sqlcommand

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian Thanks, Now its working fine... Thanks all for your responses. Have a nice day... :)

Comment: @SantoshKumar Did the Change i said helped you? im moving my comments to answer, so it would be useful for someone in the future and please mark it as answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it helped you, i am changing the comment as an answer

Query was first declared as string so change it to sqlcommand as given below

```
SqlCommand query = new sqlcommand(); 
query.commandText = "select Top 10..."
```

Final Version:

```
SqlCommand query = new sqlcommand();   
query.commandText = "select Top 10    
                 Name,
                 R_Line2,
                 BirthDate,
                 BirthTime,
                 Height,
                 Weight,
                 BirthCity,
                 BirthCountry,
                 FatherName,
                 MonthlyIncome,
                 FamilyIncome,
                 Add1,
                 Add2,
                 PinCode,
                 Tel1,
                 Tel2
          from InpRegistration  
          where DateDiff('yyyy', [Birthdate],
                  Now()) BETWEEN @AgeFrom AND
                  @AgeTo and Weight BETWEEN @MinWeight AND 
                  @MaxWeight and Height BETWEEN @MinHeight AND @MaxHeight and   
                  MonthlyIncome BETWEEN @MinIncome AND @MaxIncome";

connf.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data   Source=D:\project\Milan_Data.mdb";

connf.Open();

   OleDbCommand cmdf = new OleDbCommand(query, connf);

    cmdf.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeFrom", ddlminage.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeTo", ddlmaxage.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinWeight", ddlweightmin.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxWeight", ddlweightmax.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinHeight", ddlheightmin.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxHeight", ddlheightmax.SelectedValue);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinIncome", ddlminincome.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmdf.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinIncome", ddlmaxincome.SelectedItem.Text);

        OleDbDataAdapter daf = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdf);
        DataSet dsf = new DataSet();
        daf.Fill(dsf);
        Repeater2.DataSource = dsf;
        Repeater2.DataBind();


        connf.Close();
```

Comment: Its a tough slog to work that hard and not get marked an answer, +1 for the effort. :).  th1rdey3 is right however, you should fix that one little typo.

Comment: @paqogomez and Th1rdey3 thanks i have edited the answer now.. :)

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian Sorry for late marking your reply as "Answer". Actually, I was busy with my project and didn't get them. Hope you don't mind..